# Do infinite dimensional vector spaces have ordered bases?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

I am still getting used to what works in infinite dimensions and what doesn't. I have two infinite dimensional spaces $V$ and $W$ over $\mathbb R$. To show what I intend to do, say we can find an ordered bases of $V$ and $W$, call them $(x_1,x_2,...)$ and $(y_1,y_2,...)$ where the index set is not $\mathbb N$, it is arbitrary. I could argue this using the well ordering theorem I think.

I want to define the linear functional $\phi: V\rightarrow W^*$ by $\phi(x)(y)=a_1b_1+a_2b_2+...$, (where $x=a_1x_1+...$ and $y=b_1y_1+...$ with finitely many $a_i$ and $b_i$ nonzero) or alternatively $\phi(x_i)(y_j)=\delta_{ij}$ if the infinite series is troubling. Since we always have finite linear combinations of basis vectors, everything on that front checks out. But I feel this implies every vector space has an inner product so I might have done something wrong.

Comment: How would you multiply elements of $V$ and $W$? Please clarify what your $\phi$ function is doing. What's its domain, codomain? What do you mena by "*where the index set is not $\mathbb N$*"? Finally, the fact that you can have an ordering of such sets deosn't necessarily mean that this ordering is in any way useful or unique. What would be the purpose of defining such an ordering?

Comment: Having a (well-)ordered basis is probably not a problem, but the sum of infinitely many terms will not make sense in a general space.

Comment: @GáborPálovics Hopefully the definition makes sense now. When I say "the index set is not $\mathbb{N}$ I mean to say that by writing $(x_1,x_2,...)$ I didn't just assume the basis is countable. "What would be the purpose of such an ordering?" So that my definition of $\phi$ makes sense

Comment: @GregMartin . He is referring to a Hamel (vector-space) basis, so all but finitely many co-ordinates $a_1,a_2,....,b_1,b_2,....$ are $0.$ But I see the Q has been edited & maybe that was not originally stated in the Q.

Comment: There's nothing wrong here.  And if $V=W$ you can define an "inner product" on $V$ with this. However if we also equip $V$ with a norm, a metric, or a topology, any relationship between that inner product and the norm, metric, or topology may be interesting (or troublesome)....  The Axiom of Choice (equivalently, Zorn's Lemma, equivalently the well-ordering principle) is actually equivalent to each of a very long list of results, including "Every vector space has a Hamel basis".

Comment: I think you're right about the editing. PS: it's better if we don't assume that anonymous users are male.